# ActiveRecord User.find(:id) is giving an error while the record exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have an issue with my rails project. There is a user that is not being returned when trying to fetch the record using `find(:id)` while the record is being fetched when using `User.find_by(:email)`

Here is an example:
`User.find(333)
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find User with 'id'= 333`

````
```User.find_by(email: "example@me.com")
=> #<User id: 333, email: "example@me.com", created_at: "2017-10-06 01:30:13", updated_at: "2018-01-03 22:54:31, ..."
```
````

BTW, I am using postgresql, and the project is hosted on aptible.

Thanks in advance.

**Update**

It is really strange. I was able to update another user's id to `333` without getting a conflict error. However I am not able to update any field in the original user with `id = 333`

**Replies to comments:**

````
User.find(333)
D, [2018-01-09T01:14:22.070276 #127] DEBUG -- :   User Load (1.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 333]]
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find User with 'id'=333```

User.find_by(email: "example@me.com")
D, [2018-01-09T01:38:32.350705 #127] DEBUG -- :   User Load (1.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."email" = 'example@me.com' LIMIT 1
=> #<User id: 333, email: "example@me.com", created_at: "2017-10-06 01:30:13", updated_at: "2018-01-03 22:54:31",```


User.find_by_id(333)
D, [2018-01-09T01:53:31.652219 #127] DEBUG -- :   User Load (1.7ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 333 LIMIT 1
=> nil


User.where(id: [333])
D, [2018-01-09T18:14:15.389575 #129] DEBUG -- :   User Load (1.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" IN (333)
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
````

User Model: 
(I omitted the methods in the model since they don't affect the behavior of fetching a record)

```
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
    # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable

    devise :database_authenticatable, #:registerable,
           :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :timeoutable

    # has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :cards, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :card_templates, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :provider_posts, class_name: "Post", foreign_key: "provider_id"
    has_many :foods, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :messages, foreign_key: :sender_id, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :received_messages, class_name: "Message", foreign_key: "chatroom_id"
    has_many :notifications, dependent: :destroy

    has_many :conversations, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :chatrooms, through: :conversations

    has_many :chat_messages, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :chatusers
    has_many :chats, through: :chatusers

    # has_many :partnerships
    has_many :providers, class_name: "Partnership", foreign_key: "user_id", dependent: :destroy
    has_many :patients, class_name: "Partnership", foreign_key: "provider_id", dependent: :destroy
    has_many :provider_users, through: :providers, source: :provider
    has_many :patient_users, through: :patients, source: :patient

    # has_many :schedulings
    has_many :provider_schedulings, class_name: "Scheduling", foreign_key: "user_id", dependent: :destroy
    has_many :patient_schedulings, class_name: "Scheduling", foreign_key: "provider_id", dependent: :destroy
    has_many :scheduled_providers, through: :provider_schedulings, source: :provider
    has_many :scheduled_patients, through: :patient_schedulings, source: :patient

    has_many :mobile_devices, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :hidden_messages, dependent: :destroy

    has_many :star_categories, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :starred_cards, through: :star_categories

    has_many :user_programs, dependent: :destroy

    belongs_to :profile_status
    belongs_to :appointment_frequency

    has_many :glucoses, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :healthkits, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :scales, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :progress_images, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :temp_food_images, dependent: :destroy

    # accepts_nested_attributes_for :provider_users
    # accepts_nested_attributes_for :providers

    mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
    mount_base64_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader

    mount_uploader :license, LicenseUploader
    mount_base64_uploader :license, LicenseUploader

    mount_uploader :insurance, InsuranceUploader
    mount_base64_uploader :insurance, InsuranceUploader

    mount_uploader :insurance2, InsuranceUploader2
    mount_base64_uploader :insurance2, InsuranceUploader2

    validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: true
    validates :phone, presence: true, uniqueness: true
    validates :first_name, presence: true
    validates :last_name, presence: true

    before_create :set_default_timezone
    before_create :clear_phone
    before_create :create_auth_token
    after_commit  :sync_to_drchrono_and_salesforce, on: :create
    after_commit  :create_chatroom, on: :create
    after_commit  :create_default_cards, on: :create
    after_commit  :check_pending_appointments, on: :create
    after_commit  :connect_tech_provider, on: :create
    after_update  :check_pending_appointments, if: :email_changed?
    after_update  :start_drchrono_refresh_token_worker, if: :drchrono_access_token_changed?
    after_update  :start_fitbit_refresh_token_worker, if: :fitbit_access_token_changed?
    after_update  :sync_stats_to_salesforce
    after_update  :regenerate_progress_images, if: :last_seen_at_changed?

    scope :patients, -> { where("provider != true and demo != true") }
    scope :providers, -> { where(provider: true) }
    scope :is_app, -> { where(app: true) }

  end
```

Comment: Can you show the SQL also please.

Comment: Can you try `User.unscope.find(333)`, possible you have default scopes

Comment: Can you show your User model please

Comment: @Nermin it gave the same error

Comment: Can you please also share the SQL generated by the `User.find_by(email: "example@me.com")`

Comment: Strange, what is the o/p of the `User.find_by_id(333)`

Comment: @Salil sorry for my ignorance but what do you mean by `o/p`?

Comment: output (or result) of the above query

Comment: @salil updated.

Comment: For testing. please add this `set_primary_key "id"` to your model & try to `Model.find(333)` & see what happening @MrGreen

Comment: @fool typing  `User.primary_key` is giving `=> "id"` so I don't think the primary key is the issue. Please check the updated post.

Comment: Can you also run `User.where(id: ([333])` as well as in psql `select * from users where id = 333;`?

Comment: @Jeff I posted the first query. I currently don't have access to the psql console to run the second query. I will make sure to post it once I get access.

Comment: Did you restart your console as well? Sometimes the rails console might have reference to an object if youve assigned it but it may not exist in your db. Just an idea

Comment: @Jeff Yes this issue is happening on a production server for one of our users (so it is not only in the console). I am not even able to delete the record or update any of it's attributes. Somehow the record got corrupted.

Comment: Are you sure you are checking both the queries on same database ?? I mean in one environment product might be deleted & you are checking on another environment which is replica of the original one & user stil present there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why the following worked.

In the psql console I updated the email of user `333` and then it started to work. I was able to select it. I was also able to update the email to it's original value.

Maybe it is an issue with aptible db.